# JDBC convert Boolean to mySQL compatiable Boolean type

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

There's a lot of similar questions on here but not one that answers this question specifically. How do I get from a Java Boolean to a format acceptable for a mySQL database? I've tried several different things and read some similar problems on here but nothing is working. Here's the details:

I have a mySQL database. I built it in mySQL workbench. It allowed me to specify the datatype 'Boolean' for true/false values. It represents these with 1/0. I am aware there are tinyInts of size 1 byte.

I am building an interface for the database in Java, using JDBC. Each table in the database has a corresponding Java bean class for creating instances of the table data and a tableManager class that contains the code for going back and forth between the program and the database.

The program also has a GUI. In the GUI I have three check boxes. I use `checkBox.isSelected()` to detect the state of the check box. at the time when a button is pressed. This returns a value of 'true' or 'false'. This is then used to set a Boolean value in the corresponding Java Bean class. For example:

**In the gui:**

```
private void updateContactActionPerformed (java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) { 
    Person bean = new Person(); 
    bean.setPersonID(Integer.parseInt(labelPid.getText());
    bean.setPersonName(textfield.getText());
    bean.setIsPersonNewContact(checkBoxContact.isSelected()); 
    Boolean update = PeopleManager.update(bean); //pass the bean to the manager class
}
```

**In the manager class...**

```
public static boolean update(Person bean) throws Exception {
    String sql = "Update peopleTable SET name = ? new_contact = ? WHERE person_id = ?";
    try(
    PreparedStatement stmt = conn.prepareStatement(sql);) {
    stmt.setString(1, bean.getPersonName());
    stmt.setBoolean(2, bean.getIsPersonNewContact());
    stmt.setInt(3, bean.getPersonID());

...The rest of the try/catch statement and exception handling stuff
}
```

The Value in the Bean class being set is a Boolean though I've also tried changing it to a boolean and that hasn't helped.

From other Stack posts what I'm lead to believe is that what should happen is that the `PreparedStatement.setBoolean()` method should handle converting the 'true'/'false' values into 1 or 0. This didn't work for me. So I wrote tried two different methods. The first was to convert the  true false value to an Int of value 1 or 0 and then pass it in. This didn't work. I figured this was probably because an int is bigger than a byte. So I tried converting it to a byte like this:

```
  stmt.setByte(2, (byte) booleanToByte(bean.getIsPersonNewContact()));
```

That didn't work either. I'm print lining the error messages but they're not revealing much. I can get and put string and date values in the database so it's not the connection itself.  I'm sure there must be an easy way to achieve what I'm trying to do which. Can someone enlighten me please?

```
**UPDATE**
```

Based on the suggestion below, I changed the type in the database to string and then wrote to methods to handle conversion back and forth between string and boolean in my code:

```
    //Convert Boolean to string
    private String booleanToString(Boolean b){
    if(b){
        String t = "true";
        return t;
    }
    else {
        String f = "false";
        return f;
    }
}

//convert String to Boolean
private Boolean stringToBoolean(String s) {
    if (s == "true") {
        Boolean  t = true;
        return t;
    }
    else {
        Boolean f = false;
        return f;
    }
}
```

then I used these as wrappers around my existing. For example, code as follows:

```
bean.setIsPersonNewContact(booleanToString(checkBoxContact.isSelected()));
```

Thanks for the help solving this!

Comment: If I look at the [code of Connector/J](https://github.com/mysql/mysql-connector-j/blob/release/5.1/src/com/mysql/jdbc/PreparedStatement.java#L2884) it should already do this (unless you use an ancient version of MySQL, or maybe of the driver). What is the datatype of your column, and what is the version of the driver?

Comment: Thanks Mark. I had a look. Though I went with the suggestion below, but I appreciate your advice :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A work-around

> 1. In your table set new_contact to String instead of Boolean.
> 2. stmt.setString(2, Boolean.toString(bean.getIsPersonNewContact()));

When you get the string back from the database

> 1. boolean yourBoolean = Boolean.valueOf(resultset.getString("new_contact"));

Comment: Thanks. Great suggestion! I followed your advice on changing the type in the database. I then wrote to methods one `stringToBoolean` and the other `booleanToString` and then used them as wrappers around calls to get and set fields in the person class. .